# SQL Query Question: Select all rows of n length, and then append a character

Tags: sql

I have a ZIP code column where some of the zips came in without the leading zero.

My goal is to:

1) select all rows in the zip column that are four characters in length (e.g. the zip code entries missing a zero)

and then

2) append a '0' to these columns.

I am able to select the rows:

```
SELECT zip FROM contact WHERE zip LIKE "____";
```

and I found on this site how to append the '0':

```
UPDATE contact SET zip = Concat('0', zip);
```

but how do I combine them both together into one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE contact
SET zip = Concat('0', zip)
WHERE zip LIKE "____";
```

You can also do it like this:

```
UPDATE contact
SET zip = Concat('0', zip)
WHERE LEN(zip) = 4;
```